# T4U V3 (8822bu) drivers installed on ubuntu 18.04, but cannot connect. Keeps asking password

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I'm new here. Having trouble using my recently bought TP-link T4U V3 (8822bu chipset) Wireless adapter on 18.04. I have tried mostly every trick on the net and still cannot connect to my wireless network. It fails to connect and keeps asking for password.

I have tried both of the following drivers that most solutions point to:

1. https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu (worked twice randomly)
2. https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu

The first one seemed to "work" better, it found the networks faster and did connect twice to my 5GHz network (have also tried 2.4Ghz). But it did not reconnect after that.

I also tried to put my router 5Ghz config on WPA2 PSK AES mode only.

There is another PCI express wireless card installed that i blacklisted. Really poor signal and 2.4Ghz only.

What should i do next?? Thank you in advance!

(A lot of) more info:

**uname -r -v**

`5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020`

**lsusb**

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0424:5744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1532:0037 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:2744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 22b8:2e24 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0115  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsmod | grep 88x**

```
88x2bu               2441216  0
cfg80211              704512  1 88x2bu
```

**lspci -knn | grep -iA2 net**

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:818b]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8196]
    Kernel modules: rtl8192ee
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:8677]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

**syslog** *for [https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu](https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu_)*

```
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5660] device (wlxd0374555494e): Activation: starting connection 'Oi_459D_5G' (16596e28-ee03-48ff-a0a2-61faf3a37ba4)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5662] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="16596e28-ee03-48ff-a0a2-61faf3a37ba4" name="Oi_459D_5G" pid=2323 uid=1000 result="success"
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5666] device (wlxd0374555494e): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5677] device (wlxd0374555494e): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5686] device (wlxd0374555494e): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Oi_459D_5G' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5687] device (wlxd0374555494e): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5744] device (wlxd0374555494e): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5748] device (wlxd0374555494e): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5753] device (wlxd0374555494e): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Oi_459D_5G' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5754] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Oi_459D_5G'
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5754] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5754] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5754] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5754] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451004.5755] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway gnome-shell[2323]: Object St.Widget (0x562a06e78f90), has been already deallocated - impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: == Stack trace for context 0x562a0462c330 ==
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #0 0x562a04ac6a28 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/modalDialog.js:93 (0x7fd85c3f14d8 @ 22)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #1 0x7ffc200f9d60 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd85c3b5de0 @ 71)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #2 0x562a04ac6970 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:39 (0x7fd85c3b5b38 @ 215)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #3 0x562a04ac68e0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:783 (0x7fd8061152b8 @ 409)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #4 0x7ffc200fb0d0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd85c3b5de0 @ 71)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #5 0x562a04ac6858 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/modalDialog.js:168 (0x7fd85c3f1a28 @ 92)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #6 0x7ffc200fbcb0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd85c3b5de0 @ 71)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #7 0x7ffc200fc440 b   self-hosted:914 (0x7fd85c3f12b8 @ 346)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #8 0x562a04ac67b8 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:208 (0x7fd85c3d2b38 @ 54)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #9 0x7ffc200fdaf0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:337 (0x7fd85c3d2bc0 @ 1626)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #10 0x7ffc200fdba0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:350 (0x7fd85c3d2c48 @ 100)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #11 0x562a04ac6740 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:365 (0x7fd85c3d2cd0 @ 10)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #12 0x7ffc200fef20 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7fd85c3d2230 @ 386)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #13 0x562a04ac66b0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:244 (0x7fd85c3cf808 @ 159)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #14 0x7ffc200ffb70 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd85c3b5de0 @ 71)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2323]: #15 0x562a04ac6630 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:219 (0x7fd85c3cf780 @ 15)
Apr  9 13:50:04 cashway gnome-shell[2323]: clutter_actor_destroy: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Apr  9 13:50:09 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451009.5917] device (wlxd0374555494e): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr  9 13:50:15 cashway wpa_supplicant[943]: wlxd0374555494e: Trying to associate with a8:49:4d:10:45:a8 (SSID='Oi_459D_5G' freq=5180 MHz)
Apr  9 13:50:15 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451015.2167] device (wlxd0374555494e): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Apr  9 13:50:21 cashway wpa_supplicant[943]: wlxd0374555494e: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
Apr  9 13:50:21 cashway wpa_supplicant[943]: wlxd0374555494e: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="Oi_459D_5G" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Apr  9 13:50:21 cashway wpa_supplicant[943]: wlxd0374555494e: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Apr  9 13:50:21 cashway wpa_supplicant[943]: wlxd0374555494e: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=BR
Apr  9 13:50:21 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451021.8764] device (wlxd0374555494e): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Apr  9 13:50:29 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <warn>  [1586451029.4765] device (wlxd0374555494e): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Apr  9 13:50:29 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451029.4765] device (wlxd0374555494e): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr  9 13:50:29 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <warn>  [1586451029.4788] device (wlxd0374555494e): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Apr  9 13:50:31 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <warn>  [1586451031.0468] device (wlxd0374555494e): User canceled the secrets request.
Apr  9 13:50:31 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451031.0468] device (wlxd0374555494e): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr  9 13:50:31 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <warn>  [1586451031.0476] device (wlxd0374555494e): Activation: failed for connection 'Oi_459D_5G'
Apr  9 13:50:31 cashway NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1586451031.0486] device (wlxd0374555494e): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr  9 13:50:31 cashway gnome-shell[1839]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr  9 13:50:31 cashway gnome-shell[2323]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
```

**ifconfig**

```
wlxd0374555494e: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d0:37:45:55:49:4e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**iw reg get**

```
global
country BR: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 17), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**/etc/default/crda**
`REGDOMAIN=BR`

---

EDIT:

**sudo iwlist chan**

```
wlxd0374555494e  32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
```

**nmcli device wifi list**

```
IN-USE  SSID                    MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        Oi_459D_5G              Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        Oi_459D                 Infra  8     195 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        NET_2G0D41E4            Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        CASA DA DORIS           Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        NetVirtua402            Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        carvalho                Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        Ole Telecom-45968       Infra  10    270 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        #NET-CLARO-WIFI         Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  --        
        Kalani2                 Infra  11    135 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        INTELBRAS               Infra  11    135 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  --        
        APT 202                 Infra  7     195 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        dlink-3806              Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        #NET-CLARO-WIFI         Infra  7     195 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  --        
        NET VIRTUA 200 APT 801  Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2      
        Kamile                  Infra  8     130 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        #NET-CLARO-WIFI         Infra  8     130 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  --        
        #NET-CLARO-WIFI         Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  --        
        Virginia                Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA2      
        #NET-CLARO-WIFI         Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  --        
        Rt Diogo Oi Fibra 5G    Infra  64    405 Mbit/s  15      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
```

**sudo airmon-ng**
also(don't know if useful):

```
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlxd0374555494e ??????
```

**iw list**

```
max # scan SSIDs: 9
    max scan IEs length: 2304 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
```

---

EDIT 2:
Auto channel :(

**iwconfig**

```
wlxd0374555494e  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=5.18 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo iwlist chan` and also: `nmcli device wifi list` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks!! :)
There you go

Comment: Is your router on a fixed channel 36 (good!) or auto channel select (BAD)? Is your wireless device in Managed mode? Confirm: `iwconfig`

Comment: Router is on auto :( and device on managed mode. Also posted the `iw list`.

Comment: Digging out, i saw the driver suggest it should only work on STA/Monitor mode. But on a look in the Makefile i found this: `CONFIG_WIFI_MONITOR = n`
Any connection to the issue?
source: https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: Is it also weird for no AES option on supported ciphers?

Comment: AES is sometimes also called CCMP. Please set your router to a *fixed* channel included in your output above. From the supported modes, it appears that monitor is not supported. You could try changing the Makefile but I haven't any idea if it works.

Comment: Ok. I set it to a fixed channel. 
Supported interface modes: IBSS, managed, AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO.  Is it your intent to monitor, aircrack, etc.? no, it is not. My intent is just connecting to the network haha :).

Comment: Now is there any improvement? Does NM still prompt for the password continually?

Comment: Partial solution. Posted answer. Thanks @chili555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial solution**

Driver: https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu
Mode: Managed
Fixed channel.
Fixed channel bandwidth on 40MHz.
WPA/WPA2 AES only.

I got a routine to make it work haha

1. Put the USB adapter
2. Try to connect
3. Forget connection
4. Try to connect again
5. Cancel when it asks for password again
6. Turn off wifi
7. Remove adapter
8. Reboot
9. Login
10. Connect adapter
11. Turn on wifi
12. Connect! LOL :)

I have no idea of why this works, but i was able to reliably connect three times on a row with these steps. So i have to do steps 3-7 every time i shut down. It sucks a litte bit. I also have to put the DNS servers every time cause its a new connection.

I hope it helps others, but would be nice to solve it. any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04. In my case, the problem was I didn't install DKMS as documented. I just pasted those lines with USB adapter connected and now it works:

## DKMS

Automatically rebuilds and installs on kernel updates. DKMS is in official sources of Ubuntu, for installation do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
```

Then install the module using dkms do in source dir:

```
sudo dkms add .

sudo dkms install -m 88x2bu -v 1.1
```

In order to uninstall the module:

```
sudo dkms remove -m 88x2bu -v 1.1 --all
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/88x2bu-1.1
```