# ASUS USB-AC53 Nano on Ubuntu 20.04, is recognized, but cannot connect, keeps asking for password

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, asus, realtek-wireless

I have bought ASUS USB-AC53 Nano wifi adapter, and am trying to make it work on Ubuntu.
So far I have tried all possible steps I found on the google.
I have used drivers from these repos:

1. https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu
2. https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu

Both were built and installed successfully, and usb adapter was recognized.
However, when I try to connect to my wifi network and enter password, it writes that connection has failed and asks for password again.

I have seen a similar topic from a year ago: [T4U V3 (8822bu) drivers installed on ubuntu 18.04, but cannot connect. Keeps asking password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225682/t4u-v3-8822bu-drivers-installed-on-ubuntu-18-04-but-cannot-connect-keeps-ask)
However partial solution listed in that topic does not work for me.

Could someone suggest how to debug\fix this issue?

Here is some info:

**uname -r -v**

```
5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021
```

**lsusb | grep -i asus**

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0b05:184c ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 802.11ac NIC
```

**iwconfig**

```
wlxf02f746fc004  unassociated  ESSID:""  Nickname:"WIFI@RTL88X2BU"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.442 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

I do have this line in **/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**:

```
[device] wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

**My router:**

- 2.4 GHz only
- Fixed channel 7
- Fixed channel bandwidth on 20MHz.

Comment: Before anything else check your router settings: WPA2-AES is preferred, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thank you for the suggestion, I did set it to WPA2-AES, but that did not help. I have also tried to connect to my mobile phone's WiFi Hotspot, but that has the same issue of always asking for password and not connecting.

Comment: what worked for me was at the bottom post from this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu

Comment: what worked for me was at the bottom of this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu

Comment: @chris thanks for the suggestion, I have tried this one as well, and it did not work. I ended up returning this wifi adapter.